# Excess rows Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

**Note:** Multiple business hours was made available in this commit: https://github.com/dtmonterrey/fullcalendar/commit/d9848d0ae7d7dae0f0340c62ce38b8acc0d03b62

I'm working with FullCalendar and I have an excess row after I've set:

```
scrollTime: "08:00:00",
minTime:    "08:00:00",
maxTime:    "19:00:00",
```

**Image**

[image: Excess Rows]

**Full Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        scrollTime: "08:00:00",
        minTime: "08:00:00",
        maxTime: "19:00:00",
        weekNumbers: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        allDaySlot: false,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectConstraint: 'businessHours',
        eventConstraint: 'businessHours',
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            var eventData;
            if (title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        businessHours: [
            {
                start: '09:00',
                end: '17:00',
                dow: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
            },
            {
                start: '09:00',
                end: '19:00',
                dow: [4]
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Jezzabeanz, what do you want exactly?

Comment: Hi @A1rPin, I'm unhappy with the extra row at the bottom of the calendar. I'm asking what is this for / how can I remove it?

Comment: Ok. Did you play with the `aspectRatio` and `height` properties already? If yes, I'll need to fiddle around with your configuration ;)

Comment: I didn't touch `aspectRatio` but I did play with height. I decided not to mess with the height since I'm trying to keep it as responsive as possible.

Comment: don't mess more with height if you are changing the hight dynamically then re render the calendar as well.

Comment: As I said, I decided not to mess with the height. Any ideas on what those rows are for? Valar Dohaeris.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact issue as you, using FullCalendar v2.4.0.  I think the best option would be changing the aspectRatio property from 1.35 to 1.5 (or any larger float number).